# Possible to do fileupload with form submit(asp.net mvc + jquery ajax)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, file-upload

I am wondering if this is possible or not(if not any suggestions).

I have an asp.net mvc 3 site that will have a form with many fields. This form will be submitted by ajax through jquery library.

I want to allow the user to upload one image. I know there are uploaders for jquery that I can use but from what I seen is they got their own upload button.

I am wondering if it is possible to have they select the image but not upload. They then hit the submit button and then everything gets submitted in one go.

Or do I have to first specially upload the image and store it in a session or something then when they submit the form put everything together and do whatever is needed?

Comment: This is not that easy to handle Ajax File Upload. The plugins use IFRAME to do that job. These are great ones: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ and http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload.

Comment: what would my view-model datatype be?. I will try the 2nd one out as it seems to do the same thing as jquery.serializeArray() does.

Comment: Here you can see a simple example: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx. Hey, when you finish the upload part, don't forget to give the user some feedbacks about what's happening, like showing a loading image and disabling the Send button (it's very important to avoid server congestion).

Comment: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started  jQuery form plugin is the best way!!

Comment: I was looking in malsup form plugin. I am wondering do you know if I just use the formSerialize option if that will work with uploading. I am actually using another plugin called ajaxmanager and if I use ajaxSubmit(). I don't think I will be able to use that plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way if you are using FileUpload and Ajax together. There are several plug-in available for this. 
        1.Uploadify
        2.jQuery Form Plugin
    Hope this information help you. If you still want to do normal way than wait until HTML5 become popular.